# remove focus on textboxGotfocus event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a custNametextbox which derives its value from db on GotFocus event handler once user puts customerID.
A message dialogbox shows if customerID exists or not in the database.

My Problem is : the messagebox keeps showing after clicking OK button.(probably because i still have my focus on custNametextbox)
My question is : how can i remove focus from the custNametextBox after clicking OK button in the dialog box. How can i pull out from the textbox.GotFocus event handler. 
here are my codes

```
Private Sub custNameTextBox_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles custNameTextBox.GotFocus
   If custIDTextBox.text<>"" Then
       getCustomerInfo(custIDTextBox.text)
   End if

End sub
Private Function getCustomerInfo(ByVal incomingID As String)
   Dim idExist As Boolean = false
   //some codes here to connect database
  //if records found set idExist=true

  If idExist = false Then
     If MessageBox.show("ID doesnt Exist","Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) Then

           //do some statements here
     Else
           'set focus to customer ID
           custIDTextBox.focus
     End If
  End if
  Return 0
  End function
```

Comment: [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) Class.

Comment: Jimi7 , please kindly explain. am new to vb.net

Comment: The ErrorProvider class is a pre-built tool which provides configurable visual clues (icons and messages) to the user when an input control doesn't contain the required data. It works in combination with the validation events that a Form and all controls provide for data validation. What I meant is, use the existing tools. See the examples in the Docs.

Comment: How do i apply that in this context. it's confusing

Comment: From the docs on GotFocus event "Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: "messagebox keeps showing after clicking OK button" The only message box I see has yes, no buttons. Also, it is `MessageBoxButtons` not `MessageBoxButton` and that If statement as written won't compile. A `Function` requires a datatype, an `End Function` and a `Return` statement.

Comment: The comment character in vb.net is the apostrophe (').

Comment: hi Mary, i have it edited now but the problem persist. the program does compile. if custID exists, the custName will be displayed on mouse focus.A message dialog box shows ONLY whenever the custID does not exist in db(this search at db is triggered by the custNametextbox GotFocus event). My main problem is to break out the dialogbox whenever i click the Yes/No button, with focus on another control other than the custNametextbox. Hope i explained myself clearly.

Comment: If user is entering Customer ID, how about moving getCustomerInfo(custIDTextBox.text) to the CustomerID Validated event?

Comment: Hi Jon Roberts, please can you show me an example cos am quite confused